# Two iOS applications running as CBCentralManager (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

To illustrate an example scenario, this is the setup of the two iOS applications (iOS App1 and iOS App2) acting as CBCentralManager and listen to Peripheral Heart Rate Monitor BLE service.

1. iOS App 1 runs in the background scanning for 0x180D UUID (Heart Rate Monitor).
2. iOS App 2 runs as active application scanning for 0x180D UUID (Heart Rate Monitor).
3. Now, Heart Rate monitor advertises its data packet.
4. iOS App 1 connects to Heart Rate Monitor and starts enabling the Peripheral characteristics notification values.
5. Heart Rate Monitor device starts sending BLE data packets readings.
6. iOS app 1 and 2 start receive data packets alternately.

I would like to lock down the BLE communication between CBPeripheral and CBCentralManager to a single CBCentralManager when there is two iOS applications running and acting as CBCentralManager.  Anyone here knows how to do it?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Marcus, thank you for your response.

To answer your question, not that the second application send a connect command to the Heart Rate Monitor device, it seems that the data stream or connection stream is already open and iOS app 2 able to receive BLE data from Heart Rate Monitor. 

I edited my question and remove step 5 to avoid confusion.